# I am able to save the filename of my image in a database but when I refresh the screen it disappears - why?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I need the image to save to the session:

Here is my code so far:

Model:

```
  function ProfileImages()
   {
    parent::__construct();


    }

  function exists($username)
    {
     $this->db->select('*')->from("profileimages")->where('user', $username);
     $query = $this->db->get();

     if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
     {

        return true;
        /*
         echo "user $user exists!";
        $row = $query->row();
        echo " and his profileimage is $row->profileimage";
        */
       }

    else

        {

        return false;
        //echo "no such user as $user!";
         }

    }


function putProfileImage($username, $img)
{


    $record = array('user' => $username, 'profileimage' => $img);
    if ($this->exists($username))
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->update('profileimages', $record);


    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('user', $username)->insert('profileimages', $record);

    }

}

function getProfileImage($username)
{

    $this->db->select('*')->from('profileimages')->where('user', $username);

    $query = $this->db->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->profileimage;
     }

     return "";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function __construct()
{
// Call the parent construct
   parent::__construct();

   $this->load->model("profiles");
   $this->load->model("profileimages");
   $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));      

} 


function upload()
{
    $config = array(

        'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
        'upload_path' =>'./web-project-jb/assets/puploads/',
         'max_size' => 10000,
         'max_width' => 1024,
        'max_height' => 768);


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $img = $this->session->userdata('img');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
//fail show upload form
if (! $this->upload->do_upload())
{

    $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $error, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

    //redirect('homeprofile/index');

   }

  else
   {
    //successful upload so save to database


    $file_data = $this->upload->data();

    $img = $file_data['file_name'];

    $data['img'] = '/web-project-jb/assets/puploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
    // you may want to delete the image from the server after saving it to db
    // check to make sure $data['full_path'] is a valid path
    // get upload_sucess.php from link above
    //$image = chunk_split( base64_encode( file_get_contents( $data['file_name'] ) ) );

    $this->img = $this->session->userdata('img');


    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->profileimages->putProfileImage($username, $img);

    $data['username'] = $username;
    $data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username);


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $data, $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');


    //redirect('homeprofile/index');
    }

 }



   function index()
  {

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $data['username'] = $username;
    $data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username);

    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    //$this->load->view('homeprofile/upload_form', $data);
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $data, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ) );
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');
  }

 }
```

View:

```
<h3><?="Profile Image"?></h3>
 <img src="<?php if (isset($img)) echo base_url($img); ?>" 
 width='300' height='300'/>
  <?=form_open_multipart('homeprofile/upload');?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" value=""/>
    <?=form_submit('submit', 'upload')?>
    <?=form_close();?> 
    <?php if (isset($error)) echo $error;?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I'm thinking would I actually be needing to save the image as a link into my database as opposed to the file name? the get profileimage function is meant to throw the image back to the screen so that it stays there. Once again thanks for all your help.

Comment: how do i do that? I was answering yes to whether answers were helpful to me or not

Comment: done :) I've gone back over helpful answers I received and amended them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
$this->profileimages->putProfileImage($username, $img);
```

You are saving the `image`, but not the path. So as you've said you need to save the actual path:

```
$img = '/web-project-jb/assets/puploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
...etc
$this->profileimages->putProfileImage($username, $img);
```

Hopefully this should help you solve the issue you have.

**EDIT**

About the `session` try to do something like:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($img); //note I've changed the name above as well.
```

Check codeigniter session class [guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) for further references.

Comment: Ok the url of the image is now showing in the database - thanks for that, but I think the problem lies with my getProfileImage function. When I refresh the page the image still disappears from the screen.

Comment: Should I be putting this session->user_data in the else part of the upload function yes? At the moment the img is still disappearin as soon as I refresh